# Iphone save picture with a different name

Tags: iphone, video, record, image

I have one application than record pictures and videos using ALAssetsLibrary . Can i customize the file name of saved image or video ?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

Nope you can't change the filename. But you can maybe save the desired name in the metadata of the asset and use that.

Cheers,

Hendrik